# Access local.php or global.php from a view (phtml)?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm wanting to put a google analytics account number into the local or global.php for each update across the application.  However, I can't figure out how to access it from the views.  Am I going about this wrong, or is there a way to do this?  What I want to avoid is putting things into every controller to pass it along.  I just want the layouts to be able to grab it.

If there's a better solution to this, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have just a code for all the pages, probably you can hardcode all the analytics code in your layout view, so it will be there for al the modules view.

If you dont want to hardcode it, or you dont want to have the code in all the pages, or you have a set of diferent layout files, then I think that the best you can do is to create a ViewHelper.

Ill try to explain it from the beginning, in case this is the first time you do this.

First, create a Module, i'd call it **Utils**.

in the modules src, you can create a folder **Utils\View\Helper** and there you create a file **Analytics.php** with the class Analytics, as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Utils\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger as FlashMessenger;

class Analytics extends AbstractHelper
{
    var $code = null;

    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        ob_start();
        ?>
    <!-- analytics-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<?=$this->code?>']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script');
            ga.type = 'text/javascript';
            ga.async = true;
            ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
    <!-- end analytics-->
    <?php

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}

?>
```

in your **module.php** create function **getViewHelperConfig** where you can define the factory for the viewhelper your about to create, likethis

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(   
            'analytics' => function($sm) {

                            $config = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
                            //now in config, you have all your configurations (local, global, etc) as an asociative array
                            $add = new \Utils\View\Helper\Analytics();
                            //you asign here the code from your merged configuration 
                            //(replace *analytics_account_number* with whatever you called it)
                            $add->setCode($config["analytics_account_number"]);
                    return $add;
        }
));
}
```

**Now, inside a view, you can simply call**

```
echo $this->analytics();
```

and the framework will search the factory, create  the object, asign the values, and call the invoke method, to return the full code to your view. And thats all. write once, run anywhere!

Comment: Of course, if you only want to access the account number, you can have the _invoke method returning just that account number instead of all the analytics code, but this is a good way of keeping the view simple, and to have google's code in its own file, which will make it easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: View Helper is what I was looking for, thanks! I appreciate the details and code.